# Show that $\int_0^a f(x)dx=\int_0^a f(a-x)dx$

Tags: integration

I don't really know where to start with this one. Can you just ignore the $f(..)$ and deal exclusively with what's inside the brackets?

Comment: Make an appropriate substitution in the RHS integral.

Comment: let $y=a-x$ then usual substitution

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Substitute $y = a-x$ and remember that $\int_{c}^dg(x)dx = -\int_{d}^c g(x)dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the $u$-substitution $u=a-x$, which gives $\mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{d}x$, so we get $$ \displaystyle\int_{x=0}^{x=a} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \displaystyle\int_{u=a}^{u=0} -f(u) \, \mathrm{d}u = \displaystyle\int_{a}^{0} -f(a-x') \, \mathrm{d}x' = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a-x=t$ and $dx=-dt$  so we have $$\int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx=-\int_{a}^{0}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{a}f(t)dt$$

Answer (score 0):

Changing the name of the integration variable on the rhs can help.
You want to prove that

$$
\int_0^a f(x)dx = \int_0^a f(a-y) dy
$$

From the rhs, the substitution $a-y = x$ gives
$$
\int_{a}^0 f(x) (-dx)
$$
which is equal to the lhs.